# Directed graph with bounded in-deg can be partitioned in a balanced way

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I want to prove that for all $n$, there exists a constant $c(n)$ such that if $G=(V,E)$ is a directed graph with in-degree bounded by $n$, it is possible to partition the set of vertices $V$ to two subsets $V_1, V_2$ in a way that for all vertex $v$ in the graph induced by $V_1$ AND in the graph induced by $V_2$ , if the vertex $v$ is with out degree $d(v) \geq c(n)$ in $G$, it
satisfies that its out degree in the corresponding subgraph will be between $\frac{1}{3}d(v)$ and $\frac{2}{3}d(v)$.

I suspect that it is the kind of statements which can be proved by the probabilistic method, using the local lemma (since there are some similar theorems proven in this way). However I couldn't figure out how to do that, will be glad for help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! To help us judge the question more carefully, and decide whether or not we want to spend time thinking about it, could you maybe tell us where this problem came from? Is it homework? Research question? Do you have any reason to believe that it is true, or should we also be looking for counterexamples?

Comment: this is a research question. I strongly believe that this statement is correct, especially because it seems like a case of the local lemma.